# Making wrapper div extend to same height as content divs

Tags: css

I have a wrapper div with a min-height set.  Position is relative and display is block.  I have two column divs floated left and set to inherit min-height.

When I have lengthy content the background color of #wrapper never extends to match the content in the column divs.

Page is here:  http://youngimaginations.dreamhosters.com/index.php

CSS is here:  http://youngimaginations.dreamhosters.com/yi.css

Can someone point out the error of my ways?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`overflow: auto` will do the trick

or a `<div style='clear: both'>` after the floated elements.

Answer (score 9):

The proper fix is called "clearfix".

Read about it [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html), you'll never look back.

Comment: yes, it will, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best.

Comment: best solution that works in all modern browsers! Thanks a lot!